# Is there a plugin for sublime text 2 for debugging python?

Tags: python, debugging, sublimetext2

Is there a plugin for sublime text 2 for debugging python? Sublime Text is a great editor for python, but once the project gets too big, I have to use other IDEs (such as eclipse) for debugging.

Do any of you *Pythonists* have a solution for this issue?

Comment: I use [winpdb](http://winpdb.org/), a cross-platform python debugger.  It does not integrate with Sublime Text 2 (which I also use).  Why is the integration important?

Comment: Maybe time for you to write a plugin for that then? :)

Comment: @JoachimPileborg :) I'm afraid I won't be able to do that before February...

Answer (score 2):

Try to https://github.com/wuub/SublimeREPL, it use pdb to debug python,and easy to install by package controller

Answer (score 1):

Try to https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PdbSublimeTextSupport
Yes, it's not exactly you wont, but something.